# How can I dynamicly set the scale of an element so it transitions to the new transform after the component is mounted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-transforms

I have a for loop that makes a couple of elements that carry a dataset that's called scale. This is the scale an element should scale to when the component is mounted. In the mounted, I search for the element and then I want to change it's transform to `transform: ScaleY(here comes the data)` . I have a class applied which has a transition. So I would like to change it's transform value so that it will translate automatically. I tried changing the style but no transition happens, it just gets set to the new transform.

**My div that gets looped which renders the correct html**

```
<div v-for="(contribution, index) in contributions" :key="index" :value="contribution" :data-scale="contribution.scale" class="contribution-layer" />
```

**The css for the layer**

```
.contribution-layer{
  position: absolute;
  transition: 5s;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: $secondary-color;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  will-change: transform; 
}
```

**And the Javascript I currently have**

```
  mounted(){
    if(!process.client)
      return;
    let contributionLayers = document.getElementsByClassName('contribution-layer');
    for(let i = 0; i < contributionLayers.length; i++)
    {
      let scaleY = contributionLayers[i].dataset.scale;
      //contributionLayers[i].style.transform = "scaleY(scaleY);"; or something like that
      console.log(scaleY); //outputs the correct scale
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use Vue `refs` ([docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)) to get the element instead of `document.getElementsByClassName` since that's the Vue way of interacting with the DOM.

Or you could simply add the style in the template at render time. I assume "contributions" is an object that includes scale properties, so something along these lines in the v-for should get what you want.

```vue-js
<div v-for="(contribution, index) in contributions" 
:key="index" 
:value="contribution" 
:data-scale="contribution.scale"
v-bind:style="{ transform: 'scale('+ contribution.scale + ')' }" 
class="contribution-layer" />
```

Note the transform property needs to be a string to work.

Comment: But that just sets the style which overrides the transform in the class so no transition happens

Comment: Putting the scale into the template vs using the `mounted()` hook would apply the data at the same time. Also, remember that Vue is reactive to data changes so if you change `contribution.scale` at any time the UI will update to the new value when it's done in the template like this.